# How to make a python executable when nothing is working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I am using python 3.6 and nothing is working for me. I just can't install any of the tools for creating an executable. I tried cx_freeze, using pip had Visual C++ errors which I fixed and then it had more errors so I downloaded a wheel and that installed and in my Scripts folder there are three cxfreeze related files, none of which are batch files and when I run 'cxfreeze' in cmd it just says it is not recognised. For some reason python is installed in appdata/local/programs... but that is set in my path so I cannot see how that doesn't work. I tried pyinstaller with both pip and the download and nothing but errors about pypiwin32 which I can't get because of some other errors.

I do not know what is happening and I do not know what to do about all of this. Can someone just help me get a tool working to create an executable please. Is this because I am using python 3.6?

Comment: I have no real idea, but when you said "I run 'cxfreeze' in cmd it just says it is not recognized", it sounds like a path problem. You might need to add the directory containing that to your system path. See this if you don't know how: http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: I have done that and I have tried running command from within the actual directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try py2app (if you are on a mac) or py2exe (if you are on a windows). The setup is relatively easy.

https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/

http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: For windows, you need to use py2exe, but yes, it will still work as well.

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial for py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial